# Way to output more than the maximum character limit in a msgbox?

Tags: vbscript

I need to display a rather long message to the user in a msgbox. However there are instances where the msgbox seems to hit it's character limit. What's a solution to this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used objShell.Popup to achieve this

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Popup messagehere
```

Comment: Don't forget to Dim objShell As Object

Comment: Cool! FYI here is the doc of objShell.Popup method https://www.vbsedit.com/html/f482c739-3cf9-4139-a6af-3bde299b8009.asp

Comment: @Gin that's true only if you declared `Option Explicit` in your VBA code, otherwise it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

use Wscript.Echo *message*
instead of MsgBox *message*

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at my [Common-VBA-Message-Service](https://github.com/warbe-maker/Common-VBA-Message-Service).The message has practically no limit and the message window expands up to 85% of the screen's width and height.

Comment: This looks great for VBA, but how can this be used with VBScript?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any knowledge about VBS. Just in case it is possible I'd like to modify the code in a way it works in both environments. But that's maybe just wishfully thinking. My GitHub repo is prepared for any kind of discussion. So if you find any useful information regarding the subject VBA versus VBS it would be great if you let me know.

Comment: It triggered my curiosity. I've had a short look on the differences. There hardly will  ever be a VBS implementation of this "Common VBA Component"  with comparing capabilities and flexibility. It took me months and still think it's not (and maybe never will be) good enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
With CreateObject("wscript.shell")
.Popup b
End With
```

where b is the variable that has all the contents that you need to display in your messagebox.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way to work around the 1023 character limit:

```
Sub testWSHEnvironment()
    Dim WshShell  As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell, WshSysEnv  As _
        CIWshRuntimeLibrary.WshEnvironment
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
    theList = "Environmental Variables:"
    theCount = 0
    For Each thisItem In WshSysEnv
        If (Len(theList) + Len(CStr(theCount)) + 4 + Len(thisItem) > 1023) Then
            MsgBox theList
            theList = "More Variables:"
        End If
        theCount = theCount + 1
        theList = theList & vbCrLf & theCount & ": " & thisItem
    Next thisItem
    MsgBox theList
End Sub
```

This will generate as many MsgBox popups as you need to display the list of environmental variables.  Note that you need to include 4 in the sum in order to take into account the vbCrLf = CarriageReturn/LineFeed and ": " for each item in the list.